# Помогите! Как правильно протестировать Junit?

Tags: java, junit

Добрый день! мне нужно покрыть тестами следующий класс, как правильно это сделать, я еще никогда этого не делал.

```
public  class FileCityProviderImpl implements CityProvider {

    @Override
    public List<String> getCityList(String path) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line;
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
            for (String s : lines) {
            }

        }
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы класс легко тестировался стоит заменить `String path` на `InputStream`. Тогда вы сможете в тесте сложить иcходные данные в строку, обернуть ее в `ByteArrayInputStream` и прогнать через метод.

Примерно так:

```
public class FileCityProviderImplTest {
    @Test
    public void testGoodInput() {
        String source = .... ;
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(source.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        List<String> cities = getCityList(stream);
        assertNotNull(cities);
        assertEquals(... , cities.size()); 
        assertEquals(... , cities.get(0)); 
        assertEquals(... , cities.get(1)); 
        assertEquals(... , cities.get(2)); 
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmptyInput() {
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes("UTF-8"));

        List<String> cities = getCityList(stream);
        assertNotNull(cities);
        assertEquals(0 , cities.size()); 
    }
}
```

---

Если вам по какой-то причине нельзя менять сигнатуру метода, создавайте временный файл методом `File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".tmp")`, заполняйте его данными и передавайте егог имя в свой метод. А дальше - так же: файл с хорошими данными, файл с плохими данными, пустой файл.